# how to output multiple webpages crawled data into csv file using python with scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have the following code below which crawls all the available pages from a website. This is perfectly `crawling` the valid pages because when I use print function - I can see the data from the `'items'` list, but I don't see any output when I try to use `.csv` as a destination file to dump the stats. (Using this command in command prompt : `scrapy crawl craig -o test.csv -t csv`),.. 
Please help me output the data into a `csv` file.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from test.items import CraigslistSampleItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

URL = "http://example.com/subpage/%d"


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "craig"
  allowed_domains = ["xyz.com"]

  #for u in URL:
  start_urls = [URL % 1]

  def __init__(self):
        self.page_number = 1

  def parse(self, response):
      hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      titles = hxs.select("//div[@class='thumb']")
      if not titles:
            raise CloseSpider('No more pages')
      items = []
      for titles in titles:
          item = CraigslistSampleItem()
          item ["title"] = titles.select("a/@title").extract()
          item ["url"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
          items.append(item)
      yield items


      self.page_number += 1
      yield Request(URL % self.page_number)
```

Comment: `for titles in titles` looks like a typo

Comment: And I don't understand why you create a items list. Why not directly `yield item` at the end of the loop?

Comment: Thanks Martin.. If i dont use items list, I'm not sure how can get all the items that were scraped from the web page ?, thats the only reason I used items list.. I tried yield item without appending, by doing so - it yields only one item that is scraped from web page (which has several items actually).. Please correct me in case If I'm doing wrongly..

Comment: as suggested by you, when I used yield item.. it is retrieving only one item per each web page that is being crawled - all other available items from web pages are ignored .. how can I get all the available items per each web page that is being crawled ?

Comment: Your xpath-statements in the loop look suspicious to me. They should start with a dot. Like "./a/@href". And as mentioned already: for titles in titles is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from test.items import CraigslistSampleItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

URL = "http://example.com/subpage/%d"


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "craig"
  allowed_domains = ["xyz.com"]

  def start_requests(self):
      for i in range(10):
          yield Request(URL % i, callback=self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
      titles = response.xpath("//div[@class='thumb']")
      if not titles:
            raise CloseSpider('No more pages')
      for title in titles:
          item = CraigslistSampleItem()
          item ["title"] = title.xpath("./a/@title").extract()
          item ["url"] = title.xpath("./a/@href").extract()
          yield item
```